# How to make specific draggable area on the jsPlumb

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsplumb

I would like to make my items draggable only on a specific area.Here is a [screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yof0htzkxj0j85a/Screenshot%202015-09-11%2015.57.36.png?dl=0) of my screen. Now, when I double click a row on the queries list, a new item is created on the flowchart area. So, I want to make these items draggable only this area. Here is my html code: (`<div id=flowchart` is the place in which I want them to be draggable)

```
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span4">

            <div id="flowchart-left-panel">

                <div id ="queries">
                    <h3>Queries</h3>
                    <select class="flowchart-select" id="query-list" size="20">
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div id="filters">
                    <h3>Filters</h3>
                    <select class="flowchart-select" id="filter-list" size="10">
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="span8">
            <h3>Flowchart Editor</h3>
            <div id="flowchart">

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

And here is my javascript code:

```
$(document).on('dblclick', '.qqq', function() {


    var newState = $('<div>').attr('id', this.text).addClass('shape');
    var title = $('<div>').addClass('title').text(this.text);
    var connect = $('<div>').addClass('ep');


    newState.append(title);
    newState.append(connect);


    $('#flowchart').append(newState);

    jsPlumb.draggable($("#"+this.text), {
      containment:parent
    });
    jsPlumb.draggable(newState);
    jsPlumb.makeSource(newState, {
           filter:".ep",
           anchor:"Continuous",
           connector:[ "Flowchart", { stub:[10, 20], gap:5, cornerRadius:5, alwaysRespectStubs:true } ],
           connectorStyle:{ strokeStyle:"#5c96bc", lineWidth:2, outlineColor:"transparent", outlineWidth:4 },
           maxConnections:1,
           onMaxConnections:function(info, e) {
               alert("Maximum connections (" + info.maxConnections + ") reached");
           }
       });

    jsPlumb.makeTarget(newState, {
        dropOptions:{ hoverClass:"dragHover" },
        anchor:"Continuous",
    });

});
```